# Can't import sys or io

Tags: python, google-bigquery, transcrypt

I'm attempting to import sys and io:

```
import sys
import io
```

but I get the following errors:

```
Error while compiling (offending file last):
    File '/Users/username/worktest/index.py', line 11, at import of:
    File '/Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py', line 293, at import of:
    File '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py', line 1026, at import of:
    File 'io', line 95, namely:
    
    Import error, can't find any of:
        /Users/username/worktest/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/worktest/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/worktest/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/worktest/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.py
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_io/_WindowsConsoleIO.js
        /Users/username/worktest/_io.py
        /Users/username/worktest/_io.js
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/_io.py
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transcrypt/modules/_io.js
        /Users/username/worktest/_io.py
        /Users/username/worktest/_io.js
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_io.py
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_io.js
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_io.py
        /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_io.js
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_io.py
        /Users/username/worktest/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_io.js


    Aborted
    
  ./index.py
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/transcrypt-loader/__target_es5__/index.js):
Error: Command failed: python3 -m transcrypt --nomin --map --verbose "index"
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
    at Object.main (/Users/username/worktest/node_modules/transcrypt-loader/__target_es5__/index.js:56:67)
Error: webpack returned an error. Try configuring `entry` in your webpack config relative to the current working directory, or setting `context = __dirname` in your webpack config.
```

I'm trying to use Transcrypt and Wrangler to get my Python script running on Cloudflare's Workers, but this issue of being unable to import these modules (which don't exist on pypi) is stopping me from doing that.

Are there any alternatives to either of these in pypi that I could use instead? If not, how do I install them locally in my path.

The actual usage of them is as follows:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout # Memorize the default stdout stream
sys.stdout = buffer = io.StringIO()

for row in query_job:
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
    print("col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

sys.stdout = old_stdout # Put the old stream back in place

out1 = buffer.getvalue() # Return a str containing the entire contents of the buffer.
```

which is performed to collect output from a Google BigQuery query. This ended up being the simplest method I could find to actually retrieve the output but I'm open to altering this as well.

Comment: do you really need it ? Do you really need `print()` if you don't display it ? You could keep it directly in variable - `out1 = "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])` or using `+=` and `'\n` to keep all text in `out1`

Comment: You're right, don't need print at all. I wrote this a while ago and reading the printed output just seemed like the quickest solution at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use very, very strange method to create string.

You don't need to use `print()` to keep it as string in variable - so you don't need `io.String()`

---

More popular is to keep all strings on list and later join them using `"\n"`

```
all_rows = []

for row in query_job:
    all_rows.append( "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]) )

out1 = '\n'.join(all_rows)
```

Which can write as list comprehension

```
all_rows = [ "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]) for row in query_job ]

out1 = '\n'.join(all_rows)
```

---

Less popular is to use  directly string with `+=` and `\n`

```
out1 = ""

for row in query_job:
     out1 += "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
     out1 += "\n"
```

You can even put `"\n"` directly in `"col1={}, col2={}, col3={}\n"`

```
out1 = ""

for row in query_job:
     out1 += "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}\n".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

---

**BTW:** if you have only 3 elements in `row` then you can use `*` in `.format(*row)`

```
out1 = ""

for row in query_job:
     out1 += "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}\n".format(*row)
```

or with list comprehension

```
all_rows = [ "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(*row) for row in query_job ]

out1 = '\n'.join(all_rows)
```

or even in one line

```
out1 = '\n'.join([ "col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(*row) for row in query_job ])
```

---

**BTW:**

If you will have to use `print()` with buffer (or with file handler) then you don't have to replace `sys.stdout` but you can use `print(..., file=buffer)`

```
buffer = io.StringIO()

for row in query_job:
    print("col1={}, col2={}, col3={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]), file=buffer)

out1 = buffer.getvalue() #
```

But I don't know if it will work with `Transcrypt` (and `Wrangler`) because `Transcrypt` may have only some part of standard modules - only modules which can be converted to JavaScript. Some functions may can't be converted because JavaScript don't have access to your disk (for security reason) and it can't use your files.

Comment: Thanks for working through this. I ended up finding a simpler solution without reading the input from what's printed that I didn't know was previously possible. Unfortunately you're correct that Transcrypt and Wrangler are still throwing errors, but hopefully I can resolve that.

Comment: Transcrypt can't convert all code to JavaScript - some functions are not available in JavaScript for security reason, some of them would need external modules but Transcrypt doesn't know it and some Python modules use C/C++ code which can't be converted to JavaScript and JavaScript can't use external libraries created in C/C++

Comment: some workaround is to use Python to create web page and send data to server which can use all Python functions and modules and it can send result to browser as HTML. And this method uses [Bokeh and Dash](https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2018-01-30-bokeh-dash-best-dashboard-framework-python) or even `Jupyter`

Comment: Unfortunately this is to be used in a larger Cloudflare Workers framework, which only allows Python in the form of transpiled JS (via Transcrypt) so I won't be able to use any of those other workarounds. I would normally do something along those lines without the need for transpiling but it's required for Workers

Answer (score 1):

Was able to rework the previous (highly inefficient) method of collecting the output using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id)
```

Much faster and simpler solution that I wasn't aware of previously. Still incompatible with Transcrypt at the moment, but at least this portion is solved.

Comment: as I know `Transcrypt` may not support external modules - only some standard modules. And it can't support modules created with C/C++ which would have to be converted to Web Assembler - see Transcrypt issues: [Possible to import any packages (scipy, numpy, pandas etc)?](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/684) but it mentions [Pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide) which uses [Iodie](https://alpha.iodide.io/) similar to [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) to use web browser to display results but code runs on server.

Comment: Yeah I ended up finding this out the hard way, but I've approved your answer as the correct one since it doesn't rely on any of these modules. Now the hard part is figuring out how to import `google-cloud-bigquery`. It has a javascript source but I'm unsure about how to add that to the python file since I can't edit the final transpiled code post-Transcrypt